# How to iterate 2 objects using the same each in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need iterate two different objects, because I want to post inside a newsfeed, my Objects are "Articles" and "news", at the moment I have this option:

```
<% list = [@enterprise.articles, @enterprise.news] %>
<% list[0].zip(list[1]) do |article, new| %>
  <%= article.name %>
  <%= new.name %>
<% end %>
```

But I can't replicate the records. How can I do this? Is there any more correct way?

Comment: It seems to me that `new` is a reserved  key word, can you try change it to something else first?

Comment: `new` is [not a keyword in Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/keywords_rdoc.html), it's just very commonly used as a method name so it tends to get highlighted by syntax highlighting tools.

Comment: Your code, though awkward, should work fine. What is the expected behavior? What's happening?

Comment: I need the post be random becuase my code expects a news, an article, a news an article, and if the following message that would be news doesn't exist, don't show the next article until the order of news is followed "

Comment: What are the relationships between Enterprise, Articles and News? Is it Enterprise has many Articles, Enterprise has many News, Articles has many News? or is it something else? Also, what are your model names?

Comment: I going to show my code inside a gist

Comment: This is my code: https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/efebc4d380264df7c3d626dc56a0dd8f

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I don't have a couple of news and a couple of articles, this one works, but if one of them is odd doesn't works, I think I'm misprinting:

```
<% @enterprise.articles.zip(@enterprise.news).each do |(article, new)| %>

    <h5><%= article.name %></h5>
    <h5><%= new.name %></h5>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there anyone who wants to help me? This is my code: https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/efebc4d380264df7c3d626dc56a0dd8f